# How to make shared data in web pages?

Tags: c#, razor, webmatrix

I am using WebMatrix with Razor to make a site.
Assume we have pageA and pageB. Is it possible to create some data( for example string s="MyString") which will be accessible from both pages? If yes then how?
Thanks

Comment: Read this http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AppState dictionary for that.

```
App.MyString = "MyString";
```

See [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior).

Comment: What Mike said. App.Something = "MyString" and you can access that on any page in your app via App.Something.

Comment: Dan-o: Erik Porter (the Microsoft Product Manager for the ASP.NET Web Pages framework at the time) provided the essential parts of the answer in his comment 3 years ago. I've updated the reply to include that. You could have done that yourself. You have edit privileges on replies, I assume? This is the kind of pedantry that makes me an infrequent contributor here.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the **Model** layer (in MVC) is for.

Comment: There is no model in Web Pages. :)

Comment: Then how is this conversation relevant? ;)